# getting an error of Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am getting an error of in the below

> Line 56:11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

```
<div className="posts_container">
{
    (userPosts.length) ?
        (
            <div>
            {
                userPosts.map((post,idx)=>{
                    <div className="smallPost">
                        <img className='smallPost_pic' alt='post_img' src={post.imageurl}/>
                    </div>
                })
            }
            </div>
        )
        :
        (
            <h1> No posts Yet </h1>
        )
}
</div>
```

please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that's passed to `.map` isn't returning anything.

So either add `return`:

```
userPosts.map((post,idx) => {
  return (
    <div className="smallPost">
      <img className='smallPost_pic' alt='post_img' src={post.imageurl}/>
    </div>
  )
})
```

or replace the curly braces with parentheses:

```
userPosts.map((post,idx) => (
    <div className="smallPost">
      <img className='smallPost_pic' alt='post_img' src={post.imageurl}/>
    </div>
  )
)
```

As a sidenote, remember to add a `key` to the `div` that is returned from the `.map` function. More about that in React's docs: [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)